# How to solve the latin1 encoding problem?

Tags: python, azure-cognitive-services

I am trying to use azure text-to-speech cognitive service, trying to convert a french using the francecentral and the encoding used is latin-1. when i post the request to azure cognitive service; this error gets raised

```
ERROR:  'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u0153' in position 14932: Body ('œ') is not valid Latin-1. Use body.encode('utf-8') if you want to send it encoded in UTF-8.
```

this is the code of my text-2-speech script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import html2text
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

# Subscription Key
subscription_key = 'subscription_key'
# region
location = "francecentral"
# Chemin de l'emplacemennt des audio
output_folder = "./text2speech/audioBooks"
text = ""
text = text.encode()
url = "http://bookstore.com/cleanbook.php?idbook=1506219"
html = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.content, features="html.parser")

# kill all script and style elements
for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
    script.extract()    # rip it out

# get text
text = soup.get_text()
h = html2text.HTML2Text()
# Ignore converting links from HTML
h.ignore_links = True

# speech = h.handle(text)
speech = h.handle(text).replace("\n", " ").replace(".", ". ")
if not os.path.exists(output_folder):
    os.makedirs(output_folder)

# Fonction qui fetch le token de l api Azure (un token est valide pour 10 minutes)
def get_token():
    # API du tokenn
    token_url = "https://{}.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken".format(location)
    # header avec la valeur du subscription Key
    headers = {
        'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key' : subscription_key
    }
    # Envoi de requete pour la recuperation du tokenn
    response = requests.post(token_url, headers=headers)
    access_token = str(response.text)
    return access_token
# Fonction qui envoi une requete qui gennere un mp3 du text
def generate_speech(input_text, outfile, token):
    # URL De l 'api de la region 
    url = "https://{}.tts.speech.microsoft.com/cognitiveservices/v1".format(location)
    # Header avec la valeur du token
    header = {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer '+str(token),
        'Content-Type': 'application/ssml+xml;', #Type du data du body obbligatoirememnnt SSML
        'X-Microsoft-OutputFormat': 'audio-48khz-192kbitrate-mono-mp3', #Qualite du son.
    }
    # SSML Data avec le contenu a convertire en speech et les valeur qui defini la langue et le gender
    data = "<speak xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis' xmlns:mstts='http://www.w3.org/2001/mstts' xmlns:emo='http://www.w3.org/2009/10/emotionml' version='1.0' xml:lang='en-US'><voice name='fr-FR-DeniseNeural'><prosody rate='0%' pitch='0%'>{}</prosody></voice></speak>".format(input_text)

    # Evoi de requete qui recupere le mp3
    try:
        response = requests.post(url, headers=header, data=data)
        print(text)
        response.raise_for_status()
        #Output du fichier dans le folder des audioBook
        with open(outfile, "wb") as file:
            file.write(response.content)
        response.close()
    except Exception as e:
        print("ERROR: ", e)
        exit()

# Token
token = get_token()
# Fichier a ecrire en format mp3
outfile = os.path.join(output_folder, "1506219.mp3")
# Generation de l'audio en format mp3
generate_speech(speech, outfile, token)

print("DONE!")
```

the error is raised by the function `generate_speech()`,
I've been trying some solutions and sometimes i get a different error

```
ERROR:  403 Client Error: Starting September 1st, 2021 standard voices will no longer be supported for new users. Please use neural voices for your speech synthesis request on cloud or on prem. To make the change please update the voice name in your speech synthesis request to the supported neural voice names in chosen languages. for url: https://francecentral.tts.speech.microsoft.com/cognitiveservices/v1
```

and i guess it means that the cognitiveservice gets the text in the right format but i has a problem reading some characters.

What is the right combination of encoding and decoding that'll allow me to get a valid response?

Comment: Have you tried encoding the text as `utf-8`  like the error message suggests?

Comment: Looks like the second error has nothing to do with encoding of your text by the way, but rather with the way you are using the service.

Comment: @JanJaapMeijerink the service works fine when i use a text like this "Hi im ayoub Mafkoud" but doest work when encoding special characters to utf-8

Comment: the second error gets raised when i send data i utf-8 : response = requests.post(url, headers=header, data=data.encode('utf-8'))

Comment: I stand corrected, weird how it complains about voices when the encoding changes.

Comment: same goes for me tried pushing charset=utf-8 in the header but i get the same issue

Comment: when i try the demo in https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/text-to-speech/#features it works fine and i get the result needed.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by this character 'œ' \u0153 but still couldn't find a solution.